# HTTP module load error Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in Node.js and installed Node.js (version 4.2.1) on Windows 7.
If I write:

```
var http = require("http");
```

It says `undefined`, why it is triggering this error?

Comment: Did you installed http module??

Comment: If you're doing this in the REPL, it will return undefined because that is the return value of assignment. If you then type `http`, it will show you it's contents.

Comment: I just install node.js and start using it. Can you please let me know how to install http module in window 7?

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    // Send the HTTP header 
    // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
    // Content Type: text/plain
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    // Send the response body as "Hello World"
    response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://192.168.168.259:8081/');
```

Comment: Problem solved, i create a file and write the above code like server.js and run the code in browser. It is working fine getting no error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

You need to install extra modules like `http`, run this command inside the root folder of your project:

```
npm install http
```